# Лимит открытых файлов Apache

Tags: apache, limits

Обновился на Centos 7 и на домашнем сервере вылезла проблема. На сервере установлен virtualmin. Веб сервер работает на голом апаче без nginx, но с php-fpm, при помощи которого я переключаю версии php. Это мне нужно для работы.

Через какое-то время апач падает с вот такой ошибкой:

```
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Too many open files in Unknown on line 0
```

Погуглил, нашел как увеличить разрешение на количество файлов, применил.

```
# su printforms
sh-4.2$ ulimit -n
400000
```

Но падения не прекратились.
Создал на этом виртуалхосте файл php со следующим содержимым:

```
<?php system('ulimit -n');
```

Получаю в ответ 1024

Как сделать так, чтобы апач принял системные значения? Или как прописать эти лимиты в апаче? Желательно глобально. А то я постоянно новые площадки создаю или убираю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте файл */etc/systemd/system/httpd.service.d/10-limits.conf* с содержимым:

```
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=10240
```

Далее примените изменения:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart httpd
```

Действующие лимиты:

```
cat /proc/<PID>/limits
```